# Serialization of Closure is not allowed when running paginate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, closures, laravel-pagination

```
$posts = Post::where('content', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->paginate(5);
```

when I use the above Laravel code, the page shows:

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

is the above code not allowed to write like that since larvel doc didnot seem to have that info.

add:
when i change it to

```
$posts = Post::where('content', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get();
```

it show another error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links()

I searched the web and it told me to add the paginate(), which can solve the pagination link thing.  but still cannot

all code

```
   public function search(){
        $keyword = Input::get('keyword');
        if(empty($keyword)){
            return Redirect::route('postIndex');
            //->with('message',array('type' => 'alert', 'content' => '不能为空'))
        }
        $posts = Post::where('content', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->paginate(5);
        return Redirect::route('searchResults')->with('posts', $posts);
   }

   public function searchResults(){
     return View::make('frontend.search.search',['posts' => Session::get('posts')]);
   }
```

my routes:

```
  Route::post('post/search', array(
    'before' => 'csrf',
    'uses' => 'SearchController@search',
    'as' => 'search'  
  ));
  Route::get('post/searchResults', array(

    'uses' => 'SearchController@searchResults',
    'as' => 'searchResults'  
  ));
```

Add:
post model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
class Post extends Eloquent{
  use SoftDeletingTrait;
   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

  public static $rules = array(

            'title' => 'required|between:2,80',//unique, 参考users表的设置
            'summary' => 'required|between:20,300',
            'content' => 'required|min:50',

              'tags' => 'required|min:2',
    );  

  protected $fillable = ['title', 'content','summary', 'category'];

  public function tags()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
  }

    public function category()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
  }


  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
  }

   public function reviews(){
        return $this->hasMany('Review');//Review is the model of Review
   }

   public function getNumCommentsStr()
   {
    $num = $this->reviews()->count();

    return $num;
   }
}
```

//content of $keyword form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'post/search','method' => 'post','id'=>'search','class'=>'search'))}}
{{ Form::token()}}
<div class="keywordContainer">
{{Form::text('keyword', '', array('id'=>'keyword', 'placeholder'=>'keyword'))}}
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
{{ Form::submit('提交',array('class'=>''))}} 
{{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: Please show content of `$keyword` and your `Post` model

Comment: @ Marcin Nabiałek just added,thanks

Comment: why are you redirecting with those results flashed ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
return Redirect::route('searchResults')->with('posts', $posts);
```

Try changing it with:

```
return Redirect::route('searchResults')->with('posts', $posts->toArray());
```

And in `searchResults` change:

```
return View::make('frontend.search.search',['posts' => Session::get('posts')]);
```

into:

```
dd(Session::get('posts'));
```

to make sure where the problem occurs - in first method or in the method after redirection

Comment: By using your way,it shows all the posts in the searchResults page which has a first sentence like and afther that it's all the post with title and content:        array(15) { [0]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["category"]=> string(5) "share" ["title"]=> string(54) "Touch Events Instead of Click or Hover with JavaScript" ["summary"]=> string(116) "æœ¬æ–‡è®²è§£äº†åœ¨ç§»åŠ¨ç«¯ä½¿ç”¨Touch Eventsè€Œä¸æ˜¯Click æˆ–Hoverï¼Œæ¥ä½¿å¾—ç”¨æˆ·å¾—åˆ°æ›´åŽŸç”Ÿæ€çš„ä½“éªŒï¼" ["content"]=> string(12228) "

Comment: @franklee But have you used yours `$posts = Post::where('content', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->paginate(5);` first before return ?

Comment: I just have a check and i use: $posts = Post::where('content', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get();   just now to get what i have just said. ADD: and i have tried paginate(5) to replace get(), it seems the same result

Comment: @franklee So change it again into what you had at the beginning: `$posts = Post::where('content', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->paginate(5);`

Comment: seems the same result, what i am missing?

Comment: What do you mean? You are getting all the results or error? If all results, it's not possible, because I only change changing paginator into array, nothing more

Comment: It's not possible. You must be doing something wrong. I'm afraid I cannot help you then

Comment: I think it's the reason of the pagination because when i take away the $posts->links(),  it can show the page and results. But i do not know i am doing wrong,thanks

Comment: As I said you should not use view at all to find the error. But it seems you haven't followed what I wrote in answer

Comment: I did as you said to reset my code and see the results and  it can show. but in your way get() and paginate() seems all work.

Comment: So if they both work., you should now change your template when using `paginate` to use `posts` as array of results and not as collection